# How to find a SharePoint list based on its URL and list ID

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-data-factory

I have an old Azure Data Factory Pipeline which loads a SharePoint list and transfers the data into a data lake. The SharePoint list URL (sharepointsite) and list ID (sharepointlistid) are found as parameters in the ADF pipeline.

If I copy the list URL and list ID to my browser and try to access the site, the browser either says "you need access" or "site not reached". How can I reach the complete URL where the specific SharePoint list is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/get-sharepoint-list-url-by-list-id/

```
 Construct the URL to get the “list title” from list edit page like below:

 “Site URL”+”/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=”+ListID
```

So, if my SharePointsite URL is https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/teams/data-group and the SharePointlistid is 24312jsd-1252-sa45-034f-12ffhhhhhaaa, then I can access the specific Sharepoint list site by entering

```
 https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/teams/data-group/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=24312jsd-1252-sa45-034f-12ffhhhhhaaa
```

to my browser and pressing enter.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1 :**

you could try the below :

```
<WEBURL>/_api/web/lists(guid '<LISTID>')
```

if you need the title of the list :

```
<WEBURL>/_api/web/lists(guid '<LISTID>')/title
```

**Sample**

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/sitename/_api/web/lists(guid'97760918-543a-4bdb-b2e7-0f5da634a2e8')/title
```

**Approach 2 :**

Like you mentioned, you could access the setting page of the

```
WebURL/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List={<ListID>}
```

**Sample**

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/sitename/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List={97760918-543a-4bdb-b2e7-0f5da634a2e8}
```